# what is -d 9 arguments while running a csh script

Tags: shell, csh

I saw someone passing -d 9 -force arguments while executing a .csh file.

EX ./exm1.csh -d 9 -force

What is the meaning of these arguments.

Comment: Depends on the script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments are script dependent so might mean anything. However, you can reasonably assume the option`-force` is telling the script to complete even while that would overwrite or remove something.

There are more variations to expect with `-d` but it is often used to set the script in debug mode.

Have a look to the script shell content to figure out the precise meaning. Look for things like `$argv[1]` which means the first argument in csh.